# Using Test Complete unexpected window event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, testcomplete

I am using test complete with a project written in c# as a connected application.
I am now trying to use the event handler for unexpected window through my code.
Is anyone familiar with this idea?

Comment: So, do you want to handle this event handler within your C# application or within your TestComplete project?

Comment: within my C# application . I am currently using the automated QA dll in order to connect to the test complete and I want to be able to have control on the event handler for unexpected windows (I dont have winform application as shown in smart bear website example)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is to create an event handler of the needed event in the TestComplete project itself. You need to make this handler to call the needed method from your Connected Application. This can be done either by accessing the needed method via properties/methods of a visual object (e.g. the main form) or by using the CLR Bridge feature to access the method directly using Reflection.